# Sencha Cmd: Support for object/array destructuring

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

Can Sencha Cmd be tuned for newer js features or replaced by other minifiers/optimizers?
Or support coming with the latest versions anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the version has not been clarified, I will describe for 4.2.6

1. Go to root of your project and run

```
npm init
```

2. Install babel:

```
npm install --save-dev  babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
```

3. Add to your `package.json` run scripts:

```
"scripts" : {
    "build-prod": "./node_modules/.bin/babel es6 -d app --comments=false --compact=true",
    "build-debug": "./node_modules/.bin/babel es6 -d app --sourceMaps=true",
    "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/babel es6 -d app --watch"
  },
```

4. Move source code from `app` and `app.js` to another folder (for example call it `es6`)

```
mv app.js app
mv app es6
```

5. and create `build.xml` in root and paste new task into project tag:

```
    <target name="-before-build">
        <x-shell reloadprofile="true" dir="${basedir}">
            npm run build-debug
        </x-shell>
    </target>
```

Comment: The renaming part makes it a manual process, any way to fully automate?

Comment: I'm on Cmd 6.5.3 but could upgrade to anything newer

Comment: Why it's makes it process manual?
But It doesn't matter, because version 6.5 support es6 from scratch
https://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-ext-js-6-5-and-sencha-cmd-6-5-ga/

https://www.sencha.com/blog/getting-started-with-es2015-using-sencha-cmd-6-5/

Comment: Not object destructuring, which is a bummer since it's a nice js enhancement :)

Comment: Got it, i agree it's good feature. Then return to my question. Why renaming part makes it process manual? We just create new source folder for babel, old folder (app) is a destination. In the same time old folder (app) is  source folder for Sencha CMD. So we get automate pipeline. 

P.S. In my manual one step was unnecessary